# android arraylist can't set objects

Tags: android, arraylist

I set below code.

```
ArrayList<RectF> rects1x1 = new ArrayList<RectF>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<RectF>> arrayedRects = new ArrayList<ArrayList<RectF>>();
```

and make method in same class, write code :

```
public void SetDots(int many)
{



switch(shapeID)
{
case 3:
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
  {
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
       {
        rects1x1.add(new RectF(j , j , i+110 , i+50 ) ); 
       }
  arrayedRects.add(rects1x1);
}
break;
```

but I think this arraylist and arraylist can't save another arraylist or data.

what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You can... But you have create new instance of inner array before second loop... In your code you are adding the same arraylist to arraylist of arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the same ArrayList to the top level one, over and over again in the outer loop. There is no need to define rects1x1 as a field, just have it inside setDots (notice the lowercase leading "s" in "seDots", which is a java method naming convention).

You need to instantiate a new rects1x1 for every iteration of your outer loop, like this:

```
case 3:
    ArrayList<RectF> rects1x1;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        rects1x1 = new ArrayList<RectF>();
        for(int j=0; j<100; j++){
            rects1x1.add(new RectF(j , j , i+110 , i+50 ) ); 
        }
        arrayedRects.add(rects1x1);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++) 
  {
  rects1x1 = new ArrayList<RectF>();
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
       {
        rects1x1.add(new RectF(j , j , i+110 , i+50 ) ); 
       }
  arrayedRects.add(rects1x1);
}
```